# I have to type in port 80 after my website to see it (www.example.com:80 - but only with ssl)

Tags: networking, 20.04, iptables

I am new to server management and decided to learn by deploying my own website :D

The problem is probably that I misconfigured iptables / didn't configure them enough.

I have a node app running on port 8080 (https server, certificates are working well)

I ran `sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`
to reroute all traffic that goes into the 80 port to go to 8080 - that worked for the normal `http` server -> I could go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) without issue.

tcptracerroute

```
tcptraceroute 159... 80
Selected device lo, address 159, port 35499 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to 159 on TCP port 80 (http), 30 hops max
 1  ubuntu-main (159) [closed]  0.178 ms  0.064 ms  0.142 ms
```

(If it would help I can give the domain name / ip address)

netstat -ltnp

```
[sudo] password for twiggeh: 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      531/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      675/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42143         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      950/node            
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      675/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1279/node
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

[image: DigitalOcean DNS config]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default port for https traffic is 443, not 80 as for unencrypted http traffic. If you don't want to type port number after `https://www.example.com`, you should redirect your traffic from port 8080 to port 443, not 80.

Comment: Thank you so much! (You meant redirect your traffic from port 443 to 8080 :D )